# Sorting array containing range as strings in iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have a rows of data in sqlite database in range format as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

I have stored all these values in an array as String. Now, I have to sort the objects in an array, so that the result is as following and display it in a table view.

<10 cm

90 - 130 cm

240 - 300 cm

400 - 600 cm

'>700 cm

I have tried out some code.

**Sample Code 1:**

```
 var arr = ["240 - 300 cm", "400 - 600 cm ", "90 - 130 cm", "<10 cm", ">700 cm"]
 var arr1 = arr.sorted{$0 < $1}
```

But, this approach seems to be working for strings with alpha-numeric characters. So, I have tried another approach.

**Sample Code 2:**

```
var arr1 = [NSValue.init(range: NSMakeRange(240, 300)), NSValue.init(range: NSMakeRange(400, 600)), NSValue.init(range: NSMakeRange(90, 130))]
var arr2 = arr1.sorted{$0.rangeValue.location < $1.rangeValue.location}

for range in arr2 {
    print("\(range.rangeValue.location) - \(range.rangeValue.length) cm")
}
```

But, for this approach to work, I have to perform the following operation:

- Manipulate the data in the format (for ex. 90 - 130 cm) as per requirement so that I can blend it to fit in NSRange.
- For values like <10 cm and >700 cm, I have to handle it separately. May be, by inserting those values in the first index and last index after the array has been sorted, yet to try.
- After the array has been sorted, again print the value in a proper format which I have done by using for loop in above sample code.

The approach seems to be working with the trade-off of lots of time consumption and operation. I don't know how the performance will be if there are 100 rows of such data.

My question is, is there better and concise method to sort the data in range format in iOS?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Question: if the string starts with "<", does it means that it would be *always* the first element after applying the sorting? same for ">", does it means that it should be *always* the last element in the sorted array?

Comment: Yes @Ahmad F, I looked into more samples of such range data and I am pretty sure that there won't be any data before less than (<) operator and after more than (>) operator. They represent the min and max limit of the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution checks the first character of the string. If it's convertible to `Int`, use the entire string, if not, drop the first character and use that. Then perform a regular `compare` sorting with option `numeric`

```
let arr = ["240 - 300 cm", "400 - 600 cm ", "90 - 130 cm", "<10 cm", ">700 cm"]

let arr1 = arr.sorted { (str1, str2) -> Bool in
    let lhs = Int(str1.prefix(1)) == nil ? String(str1.dropFirst()) : str1
    let rhs = Int(str2.prefix(1)) == nil ? String(str2.dropFirst()) : str2
    return rhs.compare(lhs, options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending
}

print(arr1)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if you only got 100s of such entries, it will be very hard to create a *slow* algorithm. You can almost do anything you want and will not be able to recognize any performance impact - at least not on a millisecond scale.

If you have got *really large* amounts of data, and you are sorting frequently (e.g. sorting more often than the data is changed), one solution is to *denormalize* your database:

- Create a separte row `normalizedLength` or something
- parse all of your data, convert something like "90 - 130 cm" to an integer value `90` and store it into `normalizedLength`
- use `Int.max` and `Int.min` for those "> ..." and "< ..." values

This has to be done once for all your data. Then, your can sort etc. it multiple times.

Comment: Do you mean to say to create separate column normalizedLength, and store lower limit for ex. 90 in the column next to the data 90 - 130, and sort on the basis of normalizedLength.

Comment: Yes. Since the ranges do not overlap (as I guess), only the lower bound is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Although probably it is not the most elegant solution, you could achieve it by checking what is the first element for each string, thus achieve the desired sort:

```
var arr = ["240 - 300 cm", "400 - 600 cm ", "90 - 130 cm", "<10 cm", ">700 cm"]

func sortMyArray(_ array: [String]) -> [String] {
    var lessThanElements = [String]()
    var defaultPatternElements = [String]()
    var greaterThanElements = [String]()

    for srting in array {
        switch srting.first! {
        case "<":
            lessThanElements.append(srting)
        case ">":
            greaterThanElements.append(srting)
        default:
            defaultPatternElements.append(srting)
        }
    }

    return lessThanElements.sorted() + defaultPatternElements.sorted() + greaterThanElements.sorted()
}

let sortedArray = sortMyArray(arr)
print(sortedArray) // ["<10 cm", "240 - 300 cm", "400 - 600 cm ", "90 - 130 cm", ">700 cm"]
```

Note that if the first character of a string is not "<" or ">", it would be considered as `defaultPatternElements` element.

Comment: Good try. Thanks.